# How to optimize the query having less than operator?

Tags: mysql

I am using 1 million record to run this query, but never give me result even after 200 seconds, thus I kill the query. Below is the query

```
SELECT truncate((SELECT coalesce(sum(credit-debit),0) FROM trans_laga where uid = a.uid
    AND wallet_type = a.wallet_type AND status = 1 and freeze=0 and id<=a.id), 4)
    FROM `trans_laga` AS `a`
 WHERE a.status =1 AND a.wallet_type != 4 ORDER BY `a`.`id` desc
LIMIT 0, 50000;
```

Below is the explain output

[image]

Why this query running too slow, not even give me the result?

Comment: Start by providing an explain plain.

Comment: You have close to _ten_ joins, and almost no where clause or any fitlering of any kind.  I am not suprised the query is slow.  Have you done any indexing work here yet?

Comment: remove cases, add indexes ,  also use EXPLAIN to understand the processing of sql, which will show you step by step

Comment: @P.Salmon , I have updated my question

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , yes the index is already added, but some subquery is  not using those index. I have updated my question with explain output

Comment: @AhmedSunny , I have updated my question with the explain output

Comment: anyone please help me

Comment: anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
...
LEFT JOIN customer AS f ON a.customer_id=f.id
...
WHERE f.country = 'adminCountry'
```

This should be written as:

```
...
INNER JOIN customer AS f ON a.customer_id=f.id AND f.country = 'adminCountry'
...
```

Above will not make your query faster. For that you have to look at both lines in explain plan that have key=null

Comment: Not so sure moving the *country* test from `where` to `join` is really gonna help...

Comment: Maybe not for speed (except when there are a lot of records with different country) but doing an `LEFT JOIN` and  a WHERE on one of the fields make SQL behave as an inner join, so why no specify  an inner join right away?

Comment: Sorry but if it is not for speed, why is it an answer for a question about speed?

Comment: It should *not* be written that way, as the `WHERE` part applies to all the JOINs, not just this one. You haven't answered the question or indeed addressed it in any way.

Comment: @e2-e4 This means your query is badly written. I would suggest you fix the query first. Then we can focus on performance.

Comment: @TheImpaler Maybe provide first an answer *about speed*, to actually answer the question, and add in the answer/as a comment that the query "would be better written...". This is not answer, this is a comment at best.

Comment: @e2-e4 What I was trying to say that your query is defective, and Luuk is pointing out the query does have a bug that needs to be addressed; not just a minor syntax issue.